# Vue.js + Socket.io - append an element in a real time app?

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io, vue.js, koa2

I'm new to Vue.js, so wonder how this can be done in Vue instead jQuery?

The socket.io and jQuery will `append` a `<li>` **each time** when someone has typed something on the browser.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var socket = io();
            $('form').submit(function(){
              socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
              $('#m').val('');
              return false;
            });

            socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
              $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            });
          });
    </script>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

How is this done in Vue?

I tried:

```
     $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });

        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            message: "Hello World"
          },
          created: function() {
            socket.on('chat message', function(data) {
                this.message = data.message;
            }.bind(this));
          }
        });
      });
```

in my new HTML:

```
<form action="">
  <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
  <span id="app">{{ message }}</span>
</form>
```

It does not work obviously.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the complete vuejs way even without using jquery like this:

**html**

```
<div id="app">  
    <form @submit.prevent="submitMsg">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" v-model="inputMsg"/>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
      <span>
          <ul>
              <li v-for="message in messages">{{message}}</li>
          </ul>
      </span>
    </form> 
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
          socket: null,
          inputMsg: '',
          messages: []
      },
      created: function() {
        this.socket = io();
        this.socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
            this.messages.push(msg);
        }.bind(this));
      },
      methods:{
          submitMsg(){
               this.socket.emit('chat message', this.inputMsg);
               this.inputMsg = '';
          }
      }
    });
```

So  what''s happening:

- Wrapped the whole html with a div of `id='app'` so that it is controlled by vue
- added a submit event on the form using `@submit.prevent` which calls the method `submitMsg`. The `prevent` modifier prevents form from being actually submitting
- setup a `v-model` on the input which is two way data boun
- now you can use the `v-model` which is `inputMsg` to get the value of the input and use it in the form submission method
- after emitting the socket event setting the input value empty using `this.inputMsg = '';`
- in crated lifecycle hook setup a socket event listener and push message to the data property `messages:[]` which is initialized as an empty array
- loop trough the `messages[]` in your template using `v-for='message in messages'`which renders a `<li>` element for every item in `messages[]`

Comment: what is `,zthis`??

Comment: @teelou that was a typo

Comment: also, you have two `id="app"` in the html.

Comment: still there are some errors - i don't see any message on the screen.

Comment: @teelou i'll completely add the explanation and doo the formatting and let you know

Comment: @teelou finished...once have a look...I am adding this answer on a android tablet... so sorry for any typos...any further errors let me know

Comment: @teelou happy to help add any changes to he answer if there are any....  :)